# Pixelation effect

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone know how to archieve pixelation effect in AS3 which looks really smooth like this website: http://www.truly-design.com/site ??

Answer (score 5):

Effects are added to existing content in Flash through filters.  Complex effects are done with Pixel Bender filters.

**Pixel Bender Technology Center**

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender/

You can also download a lot of existing filters from Adobe Exchange.

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?s=5&o=desc&exc=26&cat=285&event=productHome&l=-1&from=3

A few that are along the lines of what you're looking for:

**Adjustable Scanlines**

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1694543

[image]

**Mosaic**

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1725524
[image: Mosaic Filter Example]

**Cross Stitch**

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1775023
[image]
<sub>(source: [macromedia.com](https://upload.macromedia.com/exchange/pixelbender/previews/crossstitch.jpg))</sub>

**Pixelate**

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1536018

[image]